# Is Android app size effected by unused imports?

Tags: android

Do unused imports or imports using * affect app size in Android?

For example, will something like importing java.util.* (instead of importing only what is used) negatively impact app size?

Does the compiler know to ignore unused imports, and if so, will the unused parts of java.util.* be ignored the same way?

Comment: Found this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Seems like it removes everything unused if not otherwise defined.
But it's better to do that by our own, except cases when you writing a library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about app file size, no real effect. What influences your app's file size are the code written and non-code resources (images, layouts etc.) packed into the APk.  If you're worried that it might load all of java.util when your app runs, then don't worry, classes only get loaded in your app's process space when there are actual code references to those classes. So if you're only using HashMap then then the class loader only loads the class hierarchy related to it, not all of java.util.

Now that said, most coding standard recommend explicitly importing the class that your code needs instead of using wildcards.  Promotes better code readability and makes it easier to resolve naming conflicts.